# React-native excludes Sharing Facebook Messenger

Tags: ios, facebook, react-native, sharing, uiactivityviewcontroller

I use react-native-share, to share a link. 
It's work great with imessage & whatapps but it's crash with Facebook Messenger (I wanted to make a facebook messenger sharing but I didn't find how to do it...)

So the question is: How I can know the facebook messenger activity type ?
I want to add it to this list:

`excludedActivityTypes: [
        'com.linkedin.LinkedIn.ShareExtension',
        'com.apple.UIKit.activity.PostToFacebook',
        'UIActivityTypePostToTwitter',
        'com.apple.reminders.RemindersEditorExtension',
        'com.apple.mobilenotes.SharingExtension',
      ],`

To prevent any crash from the user.

Regards,
Youcef

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to use web link, it simply opens the messenger app:

### Link

`<a href=”fb-messenger://share/?link=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fsharing%2Freference%2Fsend-dialog&app_id=123456789”>Send In Messenger</a>`

### JavaScript

`window.open('fb-messenger://share?link=' + encodeURIComponent(link) + '&app_id=' + encodeURIComponent(app_id));`

reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/messenger/web